# New model objects disappear after five minutes in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

whenever I create a new object in one of my models, they exist for around five minutes and then disappear. I checked in both my admin view and the queryset in the shell and they just disappear. I don't understand what's happening so if anyone has any idea, that'd be very useful.

These are the models:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    story = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character, blank=True, related_name='movies') 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

These are the views:

```
class CharacterCreateAPI(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Character.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CharacterSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

class MovieCreateAPI(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

These are the serializers:

```
class CharacterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movies = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Movie.objects.all())
    
    class Meta: 
        model = Character
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'image', 'movies', 'story']
        extra_kwargs = {'image': {'required': False, 'allow_null': True}}
        
        
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta: 
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'image', 'rating', 'characters')
        extra_kwargs = {'image': {'required': False, 'allow_null': True}}
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        characters = validated_data.pop('characters')
        movie = Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if characters:
            movie.set(characters)
        movie.save()
        return movie
```

Settings:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'core'
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
         'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
         'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
         'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
         ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
     'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
     )
}
```

Comment: is this happening when you hosting in Heroku?

Comment: @Sumithran No, I am not hosting it anywhere, just when I am running my server.

Comment: did you defined cron jobs for taking backup or something..

Comment: @Sumithran No, I am not sure what that is

Comment: Can you show me the code that creates the model instance. So I can see how you're doing it. Also you might want to call super on your subclasses if you're overwriting the create method (although i don't think that's creating your issue).

Comment: @AppHandwerker The model instance is created in the views: MovieCreateAPI and CharacterCreateAPI

Comment: @satoru interesting, as that should be doing a save(). Can you overwrite the `def perform_create(self, serializer):` method an do a manual `serizliazer.save() ` also log out that it get called. As it should be doing a save. The objects disappearing would make me think that `save()` isn't being called at all. hence it goes away after a  moment.

Comment: @AppHandwerker The same thing seems to happen, it is there for around 3 minutes and then it's there no more...

Comment: @satoru one other option could be you DB, what database are you using with this project?

Comment: @AppHandwerker I'm using the default one, sqlite3

Comment: Okay, then something is up somewhere. haha - question is what. Let me think on it.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an Exception being thrown on save()

Comment: @AppHandwerker When I create an object, there's only this in my console: POST /movie/create HTTP/1.1" 201 8307

Comment: Did you log out the overwrite `perform_create` method as I suggested, as you can check if the object is added to the DB, by `object = serializer.save()` print("object.pk {}".format(object.pk)) if it's not saved it wont have a primary key.

Comment: @AppHandwerker Nothing seems to be printed in the terminal if I add the print after the object= serializer.save()

Comment: Hmm do you have Try: exception block somewhere ?

Comment: @AppHandwerker No, I don't

Comment: try adding a. try:

Comment: @AppHandwerker Still nothing... might as well just restart the whole thing, maybe something broke in one of the migrations

Comment: Can you add your settings, especially DATABASES value ?

Comment: @Romain I added the settings.

Comment: @satoru Thanks. `'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',` surprise me. Maybe you should try `'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),` instead.